# Non Removable Presta Extension

Tags: road-bike, tire

Just got a pair of tubular [Vittoria Rally](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/vittoria-rally-tubular-tyre/) road tyres. They look perfect but the problem is that the valve is 42mm which is no good for my new awesome 50mm rims. Above all the valve core is not removable so the extenders I've got with them are useless.

The question is if there's any mean to extend the valves up to 60-80mm in this situation or should I return it back to the shop?

Thank you in advance for your advised.

Comment: Just by long-stem tubes.  Heck, it's harder to find the short stems that work best in my regular rims than to find the long ones.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yeah, I think that some bike shops don't like to stock 50 different combinations of valve lengths, tube material (latex vs butyl), width, and circumference, so it's easier just buy the longer lengths, which will theoretically work for all rim depths.  In reality, the longer valves have a tendency to break when used with normal depth rims combined with hoseless frame pumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple types of valve extension:

The extenders you have relocate the valve core.

The other kind are a plain tube which tapers with a similar profile to a normal valve, and screws onto the valve, over the existing valve core. Once the tyre is inflated you can remove the extension and tighten the valve-lock-nut.

Comment: Can you provide links to this magic extenders? Manufacturers, models, etc also would be very nice! Thanks!

Comment: http://www.topeak.com/products/Pumps/PrestaValveExtender

Comment: I think I found some of these on internet. Gonna buy it! thanks bro!

Answer (score 2):

I also would recommend finding tubes with valves of the correct length. However, if that fails, I've had success using a [presta to schrader adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DW444C6).  Often with shorter valves, there won't be enough room to attach a pump head, but there will be enough to attach an adapter, which you can then use a pump that works with schrader valves. Most pumps have the ability to do both now. I'm not sure if this will work in your situation, since you say you have 50mm rims and 42mm valves which to me would mean that there would be no part of the valve protruding from the rim.

Comment: good one! never thought of this

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the simplest thing is going to be getting tubes with the correct valve length for your rims. If your LBS won't do the exchange put it down to a lesson in what length valves you need for your flash 50mm rims.

Comment: the thing is I've bought the extensions along with tires, but they don't fit each other that's the problem. It's not that I've chosen the wrong length, I've chosen the wrong valve. But you're right. That might be a good lesson for the future ))

Answer (score 0):

I run Conti Race28 tubes (but with clinchers) on my deep rims. These tubes have removable cores so I have no problems fitting an extender.

Obviously this doesn't solve your current problem, but I'm sure there must be compatible tubs out there that will work for you.

Comment: Yeah I really hope so ))

Comment: @LoomyBear you're probably not riding much of a different setup from the pros. Someone must manufacture tyres for them! I can't see mechanics sewing special tubes in for them.